# I want to get 2 rows and 3 columns when dictionary is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Retrieving 2 rows and 3 column using pandas

but the unable to it works in csv file but how to do when dictionary is given!?

```
          import pandas as pd
          data =  {'Name':['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
                  'Age':[27, 24, 22, 32],
                  'Address':['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'],
                  'Qualification':['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd']}
          df=pd.DataFrame(data)
          df.set_index('Name')

          f=df.loc[['Jai','Gaurav'],['Address','Age']]
          print(f)
```

Still not working?

Comment: `not working` is the most useless information. If you get wrong result then show this result and expected result  in question (not in comment). If you get error message then show FULL error message  in question (not in comment). Don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides code may work correctly on out computers.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you have data from CSV or from dictionary. YOu have to only check if you really have datat which you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the set_index method in this way, you should also specify in place:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Age':[27, 24, 22, 32],
        'Address':['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'],
        'Qualification':['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
f = df.loc[['Jai','Gaurav'],['Address','Age']]
print(f)
#           Address  Age
# Name                  
# Jai         Delhi   27
# Gaurav  Allahabad   22
```

Answer (score 1):

df.set_index() shout be new object, try this instead
df = df.set_index('Name')